# Request Extended Permissions in Facebook, Django, Pyfacebook

Tags: django, facebook, pyfacebook

I'm developing an IFrame application in Facebook (using pyfacebook and Django) and could not understand the official documentation. Can someone give me a pointer on how to request extended permissions (like read_stream, publish_stream and offline_access)?

I experimented with FB Connect but I'm not even sure it's the right way to go for an IFrame application.

The following code placed in my template, pops up the alerts but no permission dialog:

```
FB.init(my_api_key, "/media/js/xd_receiver.htm");
FB.ensureInit(function() {
  alert("aa");
  FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access,read_mailbox,publish_stream");
  alert("aa");
});
```

p.s. Looks like [How to get (and use) extended permissions in Facebook with Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967438/how-to-get-and-use-extended-permissions-in-facebook-with-python-django) is relevant but I believe it involves FBML which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 15 hours of struggle (half of which was devoted to sleep) I found my problem. I forgot to configure the Connect URL field of my Facebook application. I copied my canvas callback URL, configured the base domain and now it works perfect.

I detailed the whole process here: http://phdrocks.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/getting-extended-permissions-in-facebook/

Comment: Not sure if you are comfortable in JS, but when I implemented this a few times, I found that the JavaScript API is a lot easier to use. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing now actually. User prompting is in JS but even then without the proper Connect URL configuration in Facebook application settings, it does not work.